Why DISM Get-CapabilityInfo reports 0 bytes download/install size for online missing capability
The system version is Windows 11 N (European) version, which does not include MediaFeaturePack capability.

I’m trying to identify which packages contain this capability, so those can be individually added for such a systems. I expect to get the list of the contained packages and the sizes, but instead I'm not even getting the capability size. I'm pretty sure it needs to be downloaded since adding it produces a lot of network traffic.
C:\Windows\System32>DISM /Online /Get-CapabilityInfo /CapabilityName:Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.26100.1150

Image Version: 10.0.26100.2314

Capability Identity : Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0
Name : Media.MediaFeaturePack
State : Not Present
Display Name : Media Feature Pack
Description : Installs media apps and enables Windows Media technologies.
Download Size :  0 bytes
Install Size :  0 bytes

The operation completed successfully.

